# El Capitan: Appstore says "downloaded" and "there's been an error" (stuck)

Tags: mac-appstore, data-transfer, macos

In order to download El Capitan, I clicked the "download" button in the highlighted banner of the Appstore. The "busy" wheel began to spin in the upper left, and I thought to give it some time.

After a while (and rebooting) I noticed not much happened. When I took a look at the detail page of El Capitan on the Appstore, the download button was greyed out (saying "downloaded"), but on its left it says "there's been an error'.

Now I'm not sure if it's actually downloaded (rebooted to no avail) or that I have to go through the process again. Eitherway I'm stuk because of the greyed out button (I can't do anything). Is there a way to find out if there's actually an install package downloaded on my system (and if so: where can I find it?), or could this be an issue with the Appstore itself? I must say I'm downloading the package on another mac without any problem…

Answer (score 86, accepted):

Apparently it downloaded the *OS X El Capitan installation* (under that name, or *Install OS X El Capitan*) in the Applications folder, which seems to be the download location. I could launch it from there.

Problem solved…

UPDATE: if this would occur during you *Mac OSX Sierra* download, the file you'd be looking for is "(Install) macOS Sierra" in the Applications folder.

Comment: If it's in the Applications folder, the download is complete. Prior to that it is squirrelled away in the nether regions of /usr/ where you're not meant to go looking for it.

Comment: in my case the installation file was called `Install OS X El Capitan`

Comment: This is a great answer!  It seems like a poor way of getting people upgrades to their software.

Comment: Found it. But it asked for me to delete it. So I deleted it and it seems to be installing from the app store

Answer (score 5):

me too. On my 2009 iMac, found it under Install OS X El Capitan in the Applications folder. Wasn't sure what was happening as it seemed to be stuck on Downloaded on the Mac App Store, and re-starting my computer wasn't doing anything. Seems to be running now