# If I pause an App Store update, and shut off my Mac, will it resume upon startup?

Tags: mac-appstore, data-transfer, macos

So I'm looking to get the new El Capitan update. Problem is, my internet connection is slow and I'll probably have to download it over 2 days. If I pause the download, shut off my Mac, and start it back up again, will the download resume, or will it have to start from scratch again?

Comment: This would say it does [even if it doesn't tell you] http://apple.stackexchange.com/questions/208396/el-capitan-appstore-says-downloaded-and-theres-been-an-error-stuck

Comment: @Tetsujin Not quite sure that's what I'm looking for... That question seems to be about something that happens after the download is compleme

Comment: Presumably, the download just auto-resumes. I can't test, as I already have the DL & I don't want to DL another 6GB just for fun ;)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

So I got the message "An error occurred" when it was nearly done. I gave up, shut my Mac down later that day, started it back up, tried the download again and it resumed from where it failed