# El Capitan won't resume download

Tags: macos

Yesterday I downloaded El Capitan partly via the Appstore. I didn't have the time to finish the installation, so I cancelled the download. Today I want to resume, but the download buttons don't work, and in the update tab I see "waiting..." and a pause button that is greyed out. I restarted and tried again, but nothing changed.

Is there a way to reset this installation or to resume it?

Comment: look at this question http://apple.stackexchange.com/questions/208488/el-captain-update-download-doesnt-continue-after-restarting-the-mac

Answer (score 0):

Follow these steps

App Store > purchased > check for any unfinished apps that didn't finish downloading, in my case it was Yosemite, then just click download on the app that didn't finish downloading and all your other apps should start to download including OSX EL CAPITAN. Cheers